# Не могу изменить квоту в GCP

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud, google-app-engine, gcp

Всем привет. Есть аккаунт в google cloud platform. Не триальный. Не могу изменить квоту, т.к. отсутствуют чекбоксы напротив квот. Роль owner. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём может быть причина?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

1. Чпокните на строку
2. Чекните Global (или раздел подпроекта, если будет)
3. Сделайте это со всеми API
4. Жмите Edit Quotas

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]